# Not able to connect Node.js/Socket.io Server from a Client using Websocket from a Unix System in a LAN

Tags: c++, node.js, websocket, socket.io, client-server

I have written a client application in C++ using websockets in Unix Environment trying to connect a Node.js/Socket.IO server running in a LAN connectivity. I found the server application is not responding at all. I tried a couple of other options from client side eventually getting no response from the server. Basically, i am trying to send a JSON object to the system running SocketIO server, but the client is not getting connected even if the server listens on to a Port.
Help, is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you should add code to this, both sides. also make sure that you have no firewall or anything else blocking that port

Comment: Questions about code that is not working MUST include the relevant code.  Otherwise, all you're asking for is guesses which is off-topic here.

Comment: Used WebSocket++ from client side, when i try to connect ws://localhost:3000 from Unix console to Node.js/Socket.io Server listening on 3000 port, Nothing is evoked at server end, it keeps on listening. A server code snippet =====>  var app = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", handleClient);

app.listen(3000);  ====>The connection function is not getting called.

Comment: maybe try to use port 80 or 8080 for the server so that most firewalls will have no issues...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following has been checked-

1. Server running and port is open (firewall) - Client is unable to connect the server
2. Url is correct - Client is unable to connect or url not exist
3. Listener code or receiving task is running - Client connected but when server send data to client, client didnot receive data
4. JSON format is correct and json data does not contain invalid character - client send data server but server did not received

Follow -
remove date if exists into msg for test purpose, use " to prepare JSON data, donot put / end of the url if not required. example-
1. Write url as ws://abc.com:8080/wsserver
2. JSON data as {"name":"myname","yourname":"indo","msg":"birthday"}

Comment: I have used https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp this one from Client Side, i am using connect ws://localhost:3000 to connect the Node.JS/Socket.io server listening on port 3000. The Snippet from the server side ----->                                                                               var app = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", handleClient);

app.listen(3000);  I can see a JSON format output from client end but i am unable to create a channel between these two.